# How can i get pooled output from deberta model?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Can anyone tell how can i  get pooled output form deberta model ?

Can anyone tell how can i  get pooled output form deberta model ? i would like to use it from *DebertaModel* for my classification model without using *DebertaForSequenceClassification *

Answer (score 0):

i solved it like this  :

```
deberta_model = DebertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/deberta-base")
deberta_model.config.num_labels = 1

class DebrtaRegressor(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    
    super(DebrtaRegressor, self).__init__()

    self.deberta = deberta_model
    self.sigmoid1 = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    
    
def forward(self, input_ids, attention_masks):
    outputs = self.deberta(input_ids, attention_masks)
    outputs = outputs.logits[:, : 1]
    outputs = self.sigmoid1(outputs)
    return outputs
```